# My R Code is returning could not find function "%>%"

Tags: r, dplyr

I installed dplyr, magrittr, and tidyverse onto RStudio, but my code is still returning an error with the pipe.

`dataset %>% select(Year)`

Comment: Did you load it via `library(magrittr)` ?

Comment: I used install.packages(). It worked with library!

Comment: installing the package is different  than loading it with `library()`

Comment: You need to load the package with `library()` in each R session before you can use the function.